# Wrong images loading using AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I have tiny issue in my app. I load data from JSON and then take image links and load images on cells. Im not sure i really should paste all of my code, since it may not concern the issue. Just want to point i use

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:url];
```

and in `myCell` custom class i use:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {

    [self.myCellImageView cancelImageRequestOperation];
    self.myCellImageView.image = nil;
}
```

Second code snipper fix the issue when u smoothly scroll table, tableView load correct images. But there is the trick - if u press on status bar on an iPhone (place where your clock, battery charge and carrier name appears) you may get from bottom of your table to top in fraction of second.

During that, application proceed to load wrong images (apparently, recently loaded in bottom cells), and after switching images it set correct one.

I want to admit, that problem almost didn't noticeable if u scrolling with low or medium speed, it only appears when you make enormous move from one side of tableView to another. But still, its nasty bug. How could i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: can you try calling 
[cell.myCellImageView cancelImageRequestOperation];
cell.myCellImageView.image = nil;   
in -cellForRowAtIndex  method?

Comment: @almas i call it in that method, its method just defined in other class.

Comment: as a workaround you can try removing and adding the imageview every time in cellForRowAtdexPath